# How to add value to Config file using XmlFile

Tags: xml, wix

How do I set a value using XmlFile in this section?

```
<root>
<!--<appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />-->
<level value="ALL"/>
</root>
```

i.e. I need to add this element and value

```
<appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
```

Is it possible to check if it exists and do not add?

Answer (score 7):

`XmlFile` allows for conditionally adding elements and/or attributes by specifying the `ElementPath` attribute.

The following example installs the XML file *File.xml* and then adds an `appender-ref` element with the `ref` attribute set to *RollingFileAppender* unless there already exists an `appender-ref` element. Note that the `XmlConfig` element for adding the attribute value references the other element's ID through its `ElementId` attribute.

```
<Component>
  <File Source='$(sys.SOURCEFILEDIR)File.xml'/>
  <util:XmlConfig Id="CreateAppenderElement"
                  File="[#File.xml]"
                  Action="create"
                  ElementPath="/root"
                  VerifyPath="/root/appender-ref"
                  Name="appender-ref"
                  Node="element"
                  On="install">
    <util:XmlConfig Id="CreateAppenderElement_SetRef"
                    ElementId="CreateAppenderElement"
                    File="[#File.xml]"
                    Name="ref"
                    Value="RollingFileAppender"/>
  </util:XmlConfig>
</Component>
```